# Jquery mobile change css width depending on control's class

Tags: css, class, jquery-mobile

I'm currently experiencing the bad sides of `JQM`. I've got say two drop down list controls and I want to add different width to them depending on their class. How can I do it?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlWidth1" 
        data-theme="e" </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlWidth2" 
        data-theme="e" </asp:DropDownList>
```

After rendering the `HTM`, `JQM` sets some classes and I can set the `ddl's` width like that:

```
.ui-select{
    width: 225px;
}
```

But this makes both `ddl's` width the same. Adding `css` classes to the `ddls` won't help, because I'm losing these classes after the `HTML` is rendered.

Comment: You can add it in asp dropdownlist tag.EX:
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlWidth1" Width="225px"
        data-theme="e" </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Not appropriate, also I doubt it will work anyway.

Comment: I think it should work. Or you Can you add using id instead of class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily, select box must be wrapped into appropriate **`data-role="fieldcontain"`** DIV. They are made specially for this purpose. Through them any inner form element can be modified easily.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/FvQ5c/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="ddlWidth1">
    <select>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="ddlWidth2">
    <select>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#ddlWidth1  .ui-select { 
    width: 225px;
}

#ddlWidth2 .ui-select { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Btw are there any other ways to do this without `fieldcontain`? I'm asking because I've got 3 elements in a `data-role="controlgroup"` and when I wrap one of them into `fieldcontain` these 3 elements are not on the same line any more.

Comment: Then wrap them into empty span element, just give it correct id/class. You will get same effect and because span is not bloc element they will stay inline.